# Why does PID of apps change/Is there a pattern?

Tags: terminal.app, pid

Long story short, I'm trying to write a program in Python that will continuously run the command `kill [PID of iTunes` but from some testing with the command `ps aux |  grep iTunes | egrep -v "grep|Helper" | awk '{print $2}'` and the PID of iTunes changes every time and I can't seem to find a pattern to it. Is there a pattern to it, or way to make it not increment?

Comment: Why does iTunes keep starting up? This seems like an inefficient method of continually trying to stop the iTunes process.

Comment: My TV remote logs in a random user and starts playing a song on iTunes whenever we press "play" and there's not a way to fix that without reconfiguring the entire TV remote, which would take hours. This way I can just run this program while we're watching TV and it will practically fix the problem.

Comment: Interesting. Is putting the computer to sleep not an option? On another note, this is on a Mac right?

Comment: Yes this is on a Mac, and putting the computer to sleep is an option, and the app still opens even if the computer is put to sleep.

Comment: You would probably be better off disabling the iTunes Helper - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91710/itunes-helper-still-running-even-if-it-is-off

Answer (score 1):

There is only one process that will have the same PID each time, on any session or system. That is the `init` process with will always have the PID 1. Other than that, there is no pattern.

If you use the Homebrew command `brew install proctools` it will download, build, and install `pgrep`.

Then you could use `pgrep -f <process name> | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}'`

I believe another option would be using `pkill` with the process name. In that case, I don't think you would have to know the process ID, just the process name. `pkill` would also be installed if you did the Homebrew command listed above.

If you don't want to install anything, try running this `ps axf | grep <process name> | grep -v grep | awk '{print "kill -9 " $1}' | sh`. See what it prints out in the shell to see if it will be killing the correct process.

Comment: `launchd` is always PID 1, `kernel_task` is PID 0. Are you thinking nix rather than Mac? The rest, as you say, will always be sequential numbers - in effect 'random'.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah, I was thinking nix. I think your comment is the better option if that stops it from opening automatically.